# VS 2008 Database Project missing Database References node

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2008

I have VS 2008 Pro (not VSTS DB edition) installed on my desktop and laptop, both running Windows 7, with SqlServer.  When creating a Database Project on my desktop machine, the project structure includes a folders for. Database References which is crucial to the utility of a database project

However on my laptop, when creating a database project, the project structure lacks that folder and I can't find any way to manually add a reference to a database.

I should note that the Project Wizard prompts me for a database connection on both machines, it just doesn't seem to have any effect on my laptop.  Any ideas what I'm missing to make Database Projects functional on my laptop?  I'm stumped, both installs are fresh.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is... I'm an idiot.  The slightly longer answer is that I had chosen the incorrect project type in the wizard on my laptop.  I mistakenly chose New Project -> Visual C# -> SqlServer Project.  The correct project type is New Project -> Other Project Types -> Database.

Comment: I appreciate the reply on your own question! Too often it seems like people never come back to solve their own problems when they have the answer...